# android- How set Animation for inbuilt intent activities?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, android-animation

I am developing app in which I use different animations for starting activities like follows -

```
Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainScreen.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.appear, R.anim.disappear);
SplashScreen.this.finish();
```

I want to set same type of animation for android activity like share.-

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
intent.setType("text/plain");
activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));          
activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.bottombar_slide_up, R.anim.bottombar_slide_down);
```

I am able to achieve slide up animation but cant achieve slide down animation when user presses back key.
Because its the activity which is not in my application I cant control its finish animation.
Can anyone tell me how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try start the activity with
`ActivityResultLauncher.launch(Intent, ActivityOptionsCompat)`.

You can set the enter & exit animation in the 2nd parameter using
`ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(Context, enterResId, exitResId)`.